# How to plot the cost / inertia values in sklearn kmeans?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

Is it possible to draw kmeans cost value?
I want to draw the cost value based on iteration of kmeans like below diagram[image]

Can you please refer to some relevant thread? Thank you

Comment: What library are you using or have you implemented k-means from scratch?

Comment: Not from scratch, but with from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

Comment: You can get the **final inertia** values from a kmeans run by using `kmeans.inertia_` but to get the inertia values from each iteration from kmeans you will have to set `verbose=2`. If you want to plot them however, you will have to **redirect the printed ouptut into a variable**, extract values and then plot. There is sadly no way to get the output of intertia values directly. Check my answer for details.

Comment: I have updated my answer to write a general helper function that calls a given function (that returns and prints something) and returns its printed data and returned data separately. In this case the model is returned and the printed is stored as text in a variable.

Comment: Might i suggest changing the question to `How to plot the cost / inertia values in sklearn kmeans?`. That would help others search for the question and clarify that its for sklearn kmeans. just a suggestion, do feel free to not make any changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Inertia in Kmeans

By `cost` I assume you want to plot the inertia values for each iteration that happens in a Kmeans run.

> The K-means algorithm aims to choose centroids that minimize the inertia, or within-cluster sum-of-squares criterion. Inertia can be recognized as a measure of how internally coherent clusters are.

[image]

This is what the KMeans tries to minimize with each iteration.

More details [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

---

## Printing inertia values for each iteration

You can get the final inertia value after fitting a `KMeans()` by using `kmeans.inertia_` but if you want to get inertia values for each iteration, one way is to set `verbose=2`.

```
def train_kmeans(X):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, verbose=2, n_init=1)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    return kmeans

X = np.random.random((1000,7))
train_kmeans(X)
```

```
Initialization complete
Iteration 0, inertia 545.5728914456803
Iteration 1, inertia 440.5225419317938
Iteration 2, inertia 431.87478970379755
Iteration 3, inertia 427.52125502838504
Iteration 4, inertia 425.75105209622967
Iteration 5, inertia 424.7788124997543
Iteration 6, inertia 424.2111904252263
Iteration 7, inertia 423.7217490965455
Iteration 8, inertia 423.29439165408354
Iteration 9, inertia 422.9243615021072
Iteration 10, inertia 422.54144662407566
Iteration 11, inertia 422.2677910840504
Iteration 12, inertia 421.98686844470336
Iteration 13, inertia 421.76289612029376
Iteration 14, inertia 421.59241427498324
Iteration 15, inertia 421.36516415785724
Iteration 16, inertia 421.23801796298704
Iteration 17, inertia 421.1065220191125
Iteration 18, inertia 420.85788031236586
Iteration 19, inertia 420.6053961581343
Iteration 20, inertia 420.4998816171483
Iteration 21, inertia 420.4436034595902
Iteration 22, inertia 420.39833211852346
Iteration 23, inertia 420.3583721574586
Iteration 24, inertia 420.32684273674226
Iteration 25, inertia 420.2786269304449
Iteration 26, inertia 420.24149714604516
Iteration 27, inertia 420.22255866139835
Iteration 28, inertia 420.2075247585145
Iteration 29, inertia 420.19985517233584
Iteration 30, inertia 420.18983415887305
Iteration 31, inertia 420.18584733421886
Converged at iteration 31: center shift 8.716337631121295e-33 within tolerance 8.370287188573764e-06
```

**NOTE:** KMeans re-initializes its centroids multiple times and runs up to `max_iters` for each initialization. For a single list of inertia values, you will have to set `n_iter=1` to ensure a single initialization during fitting the model. If you set n_iter to higher values, you will see multiple lists of initialization and iterations in the printed output.

---

## Plotting inertia values for each iteration

The problem is, that (to my knowledge) **there is no way of storing these inertia values into a variable using a parameter in sklearn**. Therefore you may need to write a wrapper around it to [redirect the verbose stdout into an output variable as text](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-variable-in-python) and then extracting the inertia values for each iteration.

You can use `StringIO` to capture this printed output from `verbose=2`, extract and plot.

Here is the complete code -

```
import io
import sys
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Dummy data
X = np.random.random((1000,7)) 

def train_kmeans(X):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, verbose=2, n_init=1) #<-- init=1, verbose=2
    kmeans.fit(X)
    return kmeans

#HELPER FUNCTION
#Takes the returned and printed output of a function and returns it as variables
#In this case, the returned output is the model and printed is the verbose intertia at each iteration

def redirect_wrapper(f, inp):
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    new_stdout = io.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = new_stdout

    returned = f(inp)                #<- Call function
    printed = new_stdout.getvalue()  #<- store printed output

    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    return returned, printed


returned, printed = redirect_wrapper(train_kmeans, X)

#Extract inertia values
inertia = [float(i[i.find('inertia')+len('inertia')+1:]) for i in printed.split('\n')[1:-2]]

#Plot!
plt.plot(inertia)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I have updated my answer to write a general helper function that calls a given function (that returns and prints something) and returns its printed data and returned data separately. In this case the model is returned and the printed is stored as text in a variable.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you for the extra details.

Comment: glad to help anytime.

Comment: How can we deal with random n_init value?

Comment: what do you mean? do you mean random initializations or just the number of initializations? Do feel free to raise another question with details so i can look into it. Once you do, please post the link in this chat so that I get a notification that you have asked another question :)